# ::selection pseudo-element outline property

Tags: css, selection, pseudo-element, outline

## In [this reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-selection#syntax)

#### At the bottom of the description,

They state that the `::selection` selector can use the **outline** property, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

How do I affect **outline** with this selector properly?

Comment: It says "optionally allow the use of the `cursor` and `outline` properties" so maybe nobody chose to implement it at all. (Understandably, since it would be crazy difficult to implement at all, never mind try to be consistent with other browsers in doing so.)

Answer (score 2):

An important note from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection):

> The `::selection` pseudo-element currently isn't in any CSS module on the standard track. It should not be used in production environments.

Which browser supports which properties on this pseudo-element is largely irrelevant today. You'll likely not get a consistent cross-browser experience, so you're probably better of avoiding the fringe details and stick to what each browser supports.

When `::selection` was in the Selectors Specification ([December 2005](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#UIfragments)), we would read:

> These are the CSS properties that apply to `::selection` pseudo-elements: `color`, `background`, `cursor` (optional), `outline` (optional). The computed value of the 'background-image' property on `::selection` may be ignored.

The `color` and `background-color` properties appear to be the best supported since they were the only non-optional values. Some browsers even support `text-shadow`, though it was not listed in the Specification.

I would avoid trying to achieve support for anything else cross-browser. Ultimately, keep in mind that non-standard features like this could up and vanish in the future. So don't get too attached to it.

*Implementation and Support Details*

- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection)
- [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)