# control height / line-height of ::selection tint

Tags: html, css

An aesthetic question for web designers:

I'm building a design system. I am wanting to control both the `color` and `height` and/or `line-height` of `::selection`.

I've tested out the obvious:

```
::-moz-selection {
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}
::selection {
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}
p {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

Neither `height` or `line-height` declarations render the desired results:

- Safari version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2) seems to highlight text when you
  click and drag with a tint that has a y-height of `118px`. Which I can only assume is loosely adhering to the `p` tag's `line-height` declaration.
- Chrome version 65.0.3325.181 highlights text with a tint that has a `16px` y-height and seems to ignore all of my declarations.

Is there a way to accurately control the height of the `::selection` tint with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection):

> Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used in a rule with `::selection` in its selector:
>
> - `color`
> - `background-color`
> - `cursor`
> - `caret-color`
> - `outline` and its longhands
> - `text-decoration` and its associated properties
> - `text-emphasis-color`
> - `text-shadow`

So, as you can see, the `::selection` does not support `height` or `line-height`.

Also, some of those properties [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641879/selection-pseudo-element-outline-property).

---

For a *pure CSS solution* I can only think of using `:focus` instead, but you'll have to make the elements *"focusable"* with `tabIndex`:

```css
p::selection {
  background: red;
}

p:focus {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p tabIndex="1">foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This answers my question.